# Permission denied error when accessing email folder even when logged in as root

Tags: file-permissions, centos-6, email-client

I have a box with iredmail installed in CentoOS 6.4.

When trying to access the vmail1 folder, which is the storage path for emails, It get the following:

```
[root@mx vmail]# dir -ls
total 12
4 drwxr-xr-x 4 vmail vmail 4096 Apr 27  2013 backup
4 drwx------ 2 vmail vmail 4096 Apr 27  2013 sieve
4 drwx------ 7 vmail vmail 4096 May  9  2013 vmail1
[root@mx vmail]# cd vmail1
-bash: cd: vmail1: Permission denied
[root@mx vmail]#
```

As you can see, I'm logged in as root.
What can cause this reaction, and how can I solve it?

Comment: It appears that only the owner has permissions set, and the vmail group is the owner of that directory.  Does your root account belong to the vmail group?

Comment: [root@mx vmail]# groups
root vmail
[root@mx vmail]#

Comment: root is already member of vmail group, that's what i did as one of first things

Comment: backup directory i can access without problems, sieve directory is "locked" too

Comment: The reason you can get into the backup folder is because it has read and execute access for "all users" set.  If you apply similar read access to the other folders can you get into them then? Also, after you added the Root user to the vmail group did you log out and log back in again?

Comment: yes, i logged out and in again

Comment: If you apply read access for everyone to the other folders can you get into them then?

Comment: [root@mx vmail]# chmod -R 755 vmail1
chmod: changing permissions of `vmail1': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory `vmail1': Permission denied

Comment: try `sudo chmod -R 755 vmail1`

Comment: same result, permission denied on command execution

Comment: Well I'm outta ideas. Hopefully someone with better Linux knowledge will roll through and recognize the problem.. :)

Comment: No problem. I have this headache since weeks already. Hopefully i will find a solution for it. Thanks for your try

Answer (score 3):

How is the vmail1 directory mounted? What's the full path to it? What filesystem is it on? For example, if it's a remote NFS-mounted filesystem with `root_squash` enabled, then having root permissions locally won't help you any.

A couple of other suggestions:

- Check that you really are root.  Running `id` should give something like the following.

  ```
  uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
  ```
- Check that there aren't any ACLs on the directory that might interfere with your access.

  ```
  getfacl vmail1
  ```

  It should display something like the following:

  ```
  # file: vmail1
  owner: vmail

  group: vmail

  user::rwx
  group::---
  other::---
  ```

Comment: [root@mx vmail]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),2000(vmail)
[root@mx vmail]# getfacl vmail1/
# file: vmail1/
# owner: vmail
# group: vmail
user::rwx
group::---
other::---

[root@mx vmail]#

Comment: i don't know the settings on the NFS server side.

Comment: mount is: 10.1.20.247:/STORAGE/MAIL on /var/vmail type nfs (rw,intr,vers=4,addr=10.1.20.247,clientaddr=10.1.20.248)

Comment: @AndreasHinderberger - Given that it's NFS-mounted and that your root permissions aren't working, I'm certain that it's the result of the server setting `root_squash`. I believe your options are (1) get the server to have less restrictive permissions (like mode 0750 instead of 0700), (2) remove `root_squash`, and/or (3) look into NFSv4's more advanced security options (which I have no experience with).

Comment: looks like that its root_squash on nfs server side. i was able to bypass it enabling shell for vmail user and then su vmail to get into the directory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the NFS server configuration.
Following steps solved the problem:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash vmail
su vmail
chmod -R 755 vmail
```

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. For future reference, as root, you can do `su vmail -s /bin/bash` to override vmail's shell, instead of permanently changing vmail's shell with `chsh`.